# Entity Framework - Virtual Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with EDMX. I have a question about virtual property and how to use it. Let's begin by saying I've three tables in my database :

[image]

Inscriptions.idEvent is a FK of Events.id and Enfants.idInscription is a FK of Inscriptions.id.

This is the Inscriptions model generated :

```
public partial class Inscriptions
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idEvent { get; set; }
    public string acronyme { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string prenom { get; set; }
    public string bu { get; set; }
    public byte clubsocial { get; set; }
    public double montant { get; set; }

    public virtual Enfants Enfants { get; set; }
    public virtual Events Events { get; set; }
}
```

Let assume that I want to add an Enfants to Inscriptions. How am I supposed to do that ? I thought it would be an `ICollection`, but since it's not that, I don't know what is a `virtual property` and how I add object to it.

Thanks !

Comment: You've done something wrong on your db relationships (I'm assuming you update the edmx from the db). As you see in the diagram an Inscription can have only 1 Enfant.If the associations are correct  the class will have an ICollection property

Comment: How can I change it in my Database ?

Comment: Try google,the first result should help you [sql server add one to many relationship](https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=cr&ei=0vFcWcPTPMrS-QGy2IWoCg#q=sql+server+add+one+to+many+relationship)

Comment: You see 1 --- 0..1 association? Normally it should be 1 --- *, did you change it? Or may be there is an unique constraint on  `Enfants.idInscription` column in database, so the relation is actually one to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @George Vovos and @Ivan Stoev.

I have updated my FK in SQL Server to set the relation one to many.